# How to edit RubyMine reformat code

Tags: rubymine, reformatting

everyone.

Wanted to know, is it possible to edit, how RubyMine reformats code, so that code like this:

```
some_object = {
      :long_named_item => 'value',
      :short_item => 'value'
    }

user = User.create!({
                     :nickname => 'value',
                     :age => 18
                    })
```

gets reformated like this:

```
some_object = {
      :long_named_item => 'value',
      :short_item      => 'value'
    }

    user = User.create!({
                          :nickname => 'value',
                          :age      => 18
                        })
```

or, even with js:

```
var some_variable = {
    'long_named_item': 'value',
    'short_item': 'value'
}
```

to:

```
var some_variable = {
    'long_named_item': 'value',
    'short_item':      'value'
}
```

Notice the spacing between hash item name and value

My friend said, that SublimeText does this with python code, so wanted to know, is this possible in RubyMine.

Comment: `Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Code Style | YOUR_LANGUAGE` -- check formatting options there. For your **specific JavaScript example**: yes, such alignment is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at formatting options in RubyMine, i found exactly, what i wanted..
For **Javascript**, the value i had to chose for "**Align object properties**" was "**on value**"
And for **Ruby** i had to tick option "**Align right parts of assigments or hashes**"

Both were under:

```
Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Code Style | YOUR_LANGUAGE | Other
```

Thanks to ***LazyOne***